# Submit json response not read correctly

Tags: json, extjs, submit, response

I have this code:

```
    sendData: function(){
        var me = this;
        this.getForm().submit({
            url: me.action,
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(form,action){
                if(action.result.success === true){
                    Ext.create('cp.view.ui.AlertOk',{mensaje:action.result.msg}).showDialog();
                    me.up('decoratorForm').close();
                    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gestionPaciente')[0].getStore().load();                 
                }else{
                    Ext.create('cp.view.ui.AlertErr',{mensaje:action.result.msg}).showDialog();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

When, the operation was succesful 'action.result.success' is true, and show the  dialog box. But, when is false, not show the dialog box. The json string returned is:

> {"success":false,"msg":"El dni ingresado ya existe y se encuentra
>   activo."}

And the PHP code that write the json string is:

```
$m = array('success' => false, 'msg' => 'El dni ingresado ya existe y se encuentra activo.');
die(json_encode($m));
```

Any ideas ? .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`failure`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Action-cfg-failure) callback in the options of your `submit` call.

Comment: Does that actually work? I wasn't sure.. I thought maybe the failure was only activated on an actual request failure.

Comment: Yes, contrary to `Ajax.request`, the [form submit decodes the response](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Submit), and the callbacks are called according to the success value.